# Crop out all the white in an image

Tags: javascript, css, image

Is there a command in CSS or a library in JavaScript that crops out all the white in an image? I know that there are applications where I could manually do it, but I was just wondering if there was a to do it through code.

Comment: you need an image manipulation library to detect a feature in the image http://codegeekz.com/best-javascript-image-manipulation-libraries/

Comment: What do you mean crop out all of the white. You mean select all the white, remove it and turn it transparent?

Comment: Yes. I want to put an image over a background, but I don't want the white to show.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use JavaScript to convert a PNG's white background to a transparent background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681915/is-there-a-way-to-use-javascript-to-convert-a-pngs-white-background-to-a-transp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [html5 canvas: clipping by color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348618/html5-canvas-clipping-by-color)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get rid of all the white, regardless of where it is in the image, you might be better using canvas

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=IRmPVeiZEMfzUuKdgZgH&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348618/html5-canvas-clipping-by-color&ved=0CBwQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNF2krW5jYeCbSEUJZQZDsnlsKHWlA&sig2=RdGtcI4Hs_1QabWUmoAKdA

Answer (score -1):

With HTML & CSS this is one way, but it's better if you do it in an image editing software (much more efficient).

You basically wrap the image you want to display in a container div, give it a specific height and width. Then give the image a width of 100%, just in case the the image is too small & hide overflow. Here’s the code:

HTML

CSS

```
.container { 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 200px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.container img { 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Try it out. The trick is the `overflow:hidden;`.

Comment: To who down voted, at least add a reason when you downvote - much more constructive than blind down voting.

Comment: Although it wasn't me who downvoted, the reason why your were downvoted was because your solution wasn't a solution to the problem the asker had.

Comment: So the answer above mine should get down voted too since it's not the answer? That makes no sense, lol. It adds no value. This answer at least gave them an option.

Comment: Problem is your answer does not give them an option because it does not reach the desired effect